# why this code crashes my browser?

Tags: javascript

I am forming some java script code like this

```
 var url = '<%= Server.MapPath(".") %>' + '/Variablesvariable.txt';
 alert(url);
 xmlhttp.open("GET", url , true); //  url +'/Variables/variable.txt'
 xmlhttp.send();
//alert('<%= Server.MapPath(".") %> \Variablesvariable.txt')
```

whats wrong with this?

the URL don't pass to method proper, at open method it get crashes, so am i forming the wrong URL, or some other way exist in the java script to concatenate it?

I see URL in add watch

it is forming like this

```
" url\"D:VisualStudio2010ProjectsWebSitesTinyEditor/Variablesvariable.txt\""
```

whats wrong?

Comment: Do you get a javascript error? Is it in one specific browser only? If you debug, on which line does it crash for you?

Comment: the URL don't pass to method proper, at open method it get crashes, so am i forming the wrong URL, or some other way exist in the java script to concatenate it?

Comment: Try to put try and catch and see what exception you are getting

Comment: it's probably an escape string issue. if your asp is writing out `'D:\VisualStudio2010\Projects\WebSites\TinyEditor'` to javascript, the backslashes will be interpreted in javascript as escape sequences. you need to double them up.

Comment: How should i do that, i am not getting?

Comment: so it comes out like `'D:\\VisualStudio2010\\Projects\\WebSites\\TinyEditor'`, or use the forward slash

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<%= Server.MapPath(".") %>`

This generates a physical path like `c:somefolder`. What you need to pass in is a url which is available on the web so something like **/myfolder/Variablesvariable.txt**.

So make it up like:

```
var url = '/myfolder/variables.txt';
alert(url);
```

Where you place the file variables.txt into a subfolder myfolder of your web application.

If you want to have it more dynamic you can do like this in your codebehind:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    VariableUrl = ResolveUrl("~/Scripts/variables.txt");
}

public String VariableUrl { get; set; }
```

and in the markup:

```
var url = '<%= VariableUrl %>';
alert(url);
```

So what you put as parameter into the ResolveUrl method is entirely up to you.

Comment: Yes correct you are, but for the java script code this the way i can do it, as i have done above, so i see it is not forming correct URL , how should i do that, i am not getting.

Comment: How to apply back slashes in the physical path

Comment: I updated my response after your comment. Please take a look at it.

Comment: No that is hard coded, i was dong the same, but if i deploy to the server in soeme other foleder that will be problem, thats why i want to fix it as above.

Comment: java script don't understand it even variable folder is in the same folder is in the current directory of the page, i have to make it hard coded from the root then, only it works.

Comment: I edited my reply with dynamic stuff. Disclaimer: works on my pc :-).

Comment: Could you tell me for the java script code only, in case we have only html page and have no server side scripting, how to take the root path?

Comment: I suggest you start up a new thread with this specific question.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5268/discussion-between-novicetodotnet-and-xiii)